# Firebase Google Auth for web/js not working for a few of my users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-signin

A few of my users (out of hundreds) can't login via the Firebase google auth on web/js. This has been a nightmare since I can't reproduce the bug, and I suspect there might be some tricky permissions issue.

The user clicks on the login button and is presented the popup method. (they are using latest chrome on windows 8.1). They choose the gmail account and it seems to authenticate, but then my React app doesn't receive the login (`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` returns null) and they simply see the login page again. In my firebase user management console, I also never see their email address in the list.

Here is the code in my top level react component:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    // detect a state change in auth (user logs in or out)
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
      console.log("FROM SIGNIN App User state changed: " + (userAuth ? userAuth.email : null));
      if (userAuth) {
        // do after sign in stuff        
      } else {
        // Logged out state
        this.setState({
          user: null,
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I got them to do a screenshot of the console:

[image]

There are some cors issues in their console that make me suspicious. But again, I have never been able to reproduce. Could this be some configuration issue on their end?

For sign in, I am doing:

```js
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

class SignIn extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.googleSignIn = this.googleSignIn.bind(this);
    }

  googleSignIn(event) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
  };

  render() {

      return (

            <button onClick={this.googleSignIn}></button>
      );
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think this is the reason for your problem but you don't need to use `async` with `onAuthStateChanged`: `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {...});` is ok since it just adds an observer.

Comment: Ah, I redacted some code. There were some awaits I used in that function so it was required. But yes, I don't think this is the problem. (I also tried with a redirect method and the user still couldn't login)